# Retrieving sentences based on the array of words

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string of text as below:

```
String text = "This is a sample text. Simple yet elegant. Everyone dies. I don't care. This text is nice.";
```

I also have an array of words as below:

```
String[] words = new String[] {"text", "care", "nice"};
```

Now, I need to get the sentences that contains the specific word in the array. So, the sentences to be outputted should contain either the word "text" , "care" or "nice" . The resultant output should be as below:

```
This is a sample text. //contains the word "text"
I don't care. //contains the word "care"
This text is nice. //contains the "nice"
```

To do that, I have attempted to store each sentences in an array `String[] sentences` that will produce output like this:

```
[This, is, a, sample, text], [Simple, yet, elegant] , [Everyone, dies], [I, don't, care], [This, text, is, nice]
```

Not sure where to go from here next. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Read up `contains()` method of string class. If you want to match 1 whole word better read up regex and patterns.

Comment: What happen if A Sentence matched with two different Words 
eg :- `text is a nice` Contains `text` and `nice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "This is a sample text. Simple yet elegant. Everyone dies. I don't care. This text is nice.";
    String[] words = new String[] {"text", "care", "nice"};
    String[] parts = text.split("\\.");

    for(String w: words){
        for(String sentence: parts){
            if(sentence.contains(w)){
                System.out.println(sentence +" //contains: "+w);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
This is a sample text //contains: text
This text is nice //contains: text
I don't care //contains: care
This text is nice //contains: nice
```

Comment: You can use RE to fine matching the word in a sentence.
Notice - contains will select word careful used with keyword care.
Depends on what is OP case.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public List<String> getSentencesWithWord(String searchWord, String text) {
    List<String> resultList = Stream.of(text.split("\\.")).map(s -> s.trim()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (int i = resultList.size() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (! resultList.get(i).contains(searchWord)) {
            resultList.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: most "efficient" answer.

Comment: but be careful only works with `jdk v 1.8` not lower because of lambda Expression Used. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
             String targetArr[]={"This, is, a, sample, text", 
            "Simple, yet, elegant" ,
            "Everyone, dies"
            ,"I, don't, care",
            "This, text, is, nice"};
            String[] words = new String[] {"text", "care", "nice"};
         for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
         {
           for(int j=0;j<targetArr.length;j++)
              {
              if(targetArr[j].contains(words[i]))
                 {
                  System.out.println(targetArr[j]);
                  }
               }
           }
```

where ***targetArr*** contains your array with separated data

```
 [This, is, a, sample, text], [Simple, yet, elegant] , [Everyone, dies], [I, don't, care], [This, text, is, nice]
```

Comment: In this answer it assumes that the objects are stored in collections eg ArrayList. This will not work with raw String Arrays.

Comment: yes exactly. But you could implements the logic.Bcz as mentioned they are unable to implements logic.They didn't shown his attempts .

Comment: Yeah i agree that using java.collection is better then using arrays. But from the level of the question i assume it is a school assignment to do with arrays so i just wanted to mention it about your solution. Also it wont compile since length on an array is a member variable and not a method call should be targetArr.length;

Answer (score 0):

```
[[This, is, a, sample, text], [Simple, yet, elegant] , [Everyone, dies], [I, don't, care], [This, text, is, nice]]
```

Well if you get have the above output i suppose you have and array of string arrays.

If that is the case then you can iterate through the first set and then check to see if any words in that array match.

Here is some of my code:

```
String[][] sentences = new String[][]{};
String[] keywords = new String[]{};
for (String[] sentence: sentences )
{
  boolean match = false;
  wordsLoop: for (String word : sentence)
  {
    for (String keyword : keywords)
    {
      if(word.equals(keyword))
      {
        match = true;
        break wordsLoop; // this stops the outside wordloop loop
      }
    }
  }
  if(match)
  {
    System.out.println(String.join(" ",sentence)+".");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList<String> getWordsFromSentence(String prm_objString){
      ArrayList<String> AllMatchedSentences;
      String text = "This is a sample text. Simple yet elegant. Everyone dies. I don't care. This text is nice.";

      String[] words = new String[] {"text", "care", "nice"};

      String [] AllSentence = text.split("\\."); //Split Your Text In Sentences.
      AllMatchedSentences = new ArrayList<>();
      foreach(String eachSentense : AllSentence) //Go Through with each Sentences.
      {
           for(int i=0; i<words .length; i++) // Go Through withh each Words
             {
               if(eachSentense.contains(words[i].toString())) // All Possible Match.
               //Add all Matched Sentences to Array List

                   AllMatchedSentences.add(eachSentense +" //contains "+words[i].toString()); 
             }
            System.out.println(eachSentense);
      }
     return AllMatchedSentences; //Return all Possible Sentences ias a ArrayList Object.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use java 8 features.

```
java.util.List<String> sentences = Stream.of(text.split("\\.")).filter(s -> Stream.of(words).anyMatch(p -> s.contains(p))).collect(Collectors.toList());

sentences.forEach(System.out::println);
```

should print

```
This is a sample text
 I don't care
 This text is nice
```

Comment: 'thanks but only for `Java V_1.8` not work in lower because of lambda Expression